Improving interactive SwiftUI widget responsiveness when using app intents
I have a performance issue (I guess) with my widget, let me explain first what I want to achieve.
I'm trying to create an interactive widget that acts as a calculator, The code is working well, but the widget it's not very responsive if I'm trying to quickly press the buttons.
I found a good example such as this one, that works well when buttons are pressed quickly : https://apps.apple.com/us/app/calculator-widget-simple-calc/id6465680493
Do you have any suggestions on possible improvements ? I was thinking about User Defaults performance, but not sure what to think, since I'm just using some basic stuff there.
Thanks for your help.
Here the intent I'm using when the buttons are pressed :
struct CalculatorDigitIntent: AppIntent {
    
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Calculator"
    
    @Parameter(title: "Digit")
    var digit: String
    
    init() {}
    
    init(digit: String) {
        self.digit = digit
    }
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "calculatorAmount")
        
        var calculatorAmount = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "calculatorAmount")
        
        switch digit {
        case "00":
            if calculatorAmount != 0 {
                calculatorAmount *= 100
            }
        case "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9":
            if let digit = Double(digit) {
                if calculatorAmount != 0 || digit != 0 {
                    calculatorAmount = calculatorAmount * 10 + digit
                }
            }
        default:
            break
        }
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(calculatorAmount, forKey: "calculatorAmount")
        
        return .result()
    }
}

Here is the timeline provider :
struct CalculatorProvider: AppIntentTimelineProvider {
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> FXWCalculatorEntry {
        CalculatorEntry(date: Date(), amount: 0.0)
    }

    func snapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent, in context: Context) async -> CalculatorEntry {
        CalculatorEntry(date: Date(), amount: 0.0)
    }
    
    func timeline(for configuration: ConfigurationAppIntent, in context: Context) async -> Timeline<CalculatorEntry> {
        let digits = getCalculatorDigits()
        
        let entry = CalculatorEntry(date: Date(), amount: digits)
        
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .never)
        return timeline
    }
    
    func getCalculatorDigits() -> Double {
        return UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "calculatorAmount")
    }
}

From my understanding from documentation, each time when an app intent it's called, the timeline will be refreshed.
In my view code, I just have simple buttons like this one :
Button(intent: CalculatorDigitIntent(digit: "4")) {
    Text("4")
    .font(.system(size: 20).bold())
    .foregroundStyle(Color(hex: "#252F2C"))
}


I tested the app you shared, the interactive widget doesn't feel super responsive. It seems to update every 1s
